# Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently running rails 3 and keep getting this error message when trying to subscribe a user using the stripe-gem.

**Error message:**

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:55:in `create'

**This is the line of quote the error is referring to:**

cur_employer = Employer.find_by_employer_id(current_employer.id)

Below is the chargers controller
Charges_controller.rb

```
def create
  card_token = params[:stripeToken]
  planid = params['planid']
  emply_nmbr = params['emply_nmbr']
  cur_employer = Employer.find_by_employer_id(current_employer.id)
      # Create and subscribe a Customer

 if emply_nmbr=="update_Card"
   already_subscribed = Subscription.find_by_employer_id(current_employer.id)
   customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(already_subscribed.customer_id)
   #customer.cards.retrieve(already_subscribed.card_id).delete()
  changed_card = customer.cards.create(:card => card_token)
    cust_crd = CustCard.new
    cust_crd.employer_id = current_employer.id
    cust_crd.cust_card_id = changed_card.id
    cust_crd.save
  #Subscription.where(:employer_id=> current_employer.id).update_all(:card_id=> changed_card.id)
   flash[:notice] = "Your Card Was Successfully Saved"
   redirect_to settings_path
 else
   customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :card => card_token,
    :plan => planid.to_s,
    :email => cur_employer.email,
    :description => 'App Subscription',
    :metadata => {'Name' => cur_employer.first_name << " "+cur_employer.last_name}
   )
  if customer.present?
    subs = Subscription.new
      subs.employer_id=current_employer.id
      subs.plan_id=planid
      subs.customer_id=customer.id
      subs.save

      cust_crd = CustCard.new
      cust_crd.employer_id = current_employer.id
      cust_crd.cust_card_id = customer.cards.data[0].id
      cust_crd.save

    Employer.where(:id=> current_employer.id).update_all(:paid_employees=> emply_nmbr)
     flash[:notice] = "You Have Subscribed Successfully"
     redirect_to settings_path
   end
  end
   rescue Stripe::CardError => e
   flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
end
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: `current_employer` is nil.

Comment: and where is `current_employee initializer`?

Comment: It is because `current_employer` is `nil`.How you are initializing the `current_employer`?

Comment: If you are using devise then make sure you have `authenticate_employer!` before_filter.

NOTE - It is not conventional to write such long controller actions, try moving some code out from controller to model.

Comment: Thanks Himesh. I added the before filter :authenticate_employer! in the charges controller. But when i submit the form it logs me out. I am using Devise by the way. any suggestions?